# Australian Travelling to Türkiye

Tags: visas, turkey, australian-citizens

How is it that Australian passport holders are not eligible for visa free entry status to Türkiye when countries such as NZ,UK,EU, USA and Canada are eligible? What have we done to not be on the exempt list?

Comment: Reciprocity, usually. If you're not important enough to give up the principles then that's the result.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's about politics, not travel

Comment: Visa requirements are a combination of immigration policy (what percentage of citizens of country X do not misuse the immigration system of country Y) and how country Y treats the citizens of country X. I don't see this as being strictly about politics. Asking for the reason why, is in my mind, is a valid travel question.

Answer (score 1):

> when countries such as NZ,UK,EU, USA and Canada are eligible? What have we done to not be on the exempt list?

As one comment has mentioned already: *Reciprocity, usually.*

Turkish citizens require from both Australia and New Zealand a visa, but for New Zealand the visa seems to be free of charge as apposed to Australia which charges about twice the amount that Australians must pay for a Turkish eVisa (US$60).

---

**Sources**:

- [Visa Information For Foreigners / Republic of Türkiye Ministry of Foreign Affairs](https://www.mfa.gov.tr/visa-information-for-foreigners.en.mfa)

  - **Australia**: Ordinary and official passport holders are required to have visa to enter Türkiye. Ordinary passport holders can obtain three month-multiple entry e-Visas via the website [www.evisa.gov.tr](http://www.evisa.gov.tr).

    - for Turkish citizens: [FA600 Visitor/Tourist outside Australia: AUS$ 190.00](https://immi.homeaffairs.gov.au/visas/visa-pricing-estimator)
  - **New Zealand**: Ordinary and official passport holders are exempt from visa for their travels up to 90 days.

    - for Turkish citizens: [Application cost – Citizens of Turkey do not have to pay a fee or immigration levy for this application. Each person must pay an International Visitor Conservation and Tourism Levy (IVL) of NZD $35. This is included in the cost.](https://www.immigration.govt.nz/new-zealand-visas/visas/visa/visitor-visa)

Comment: In this case it has little to do with reciprocity. UK, EU, USA and CAN all require visas from Turkish nationals, yet nationals of those countries don't need a Turkish visa. Why? Mainly because Turkey wants to attract western tourists. Australia is probably too far away to be important in this aspect and charges exorbitant amounts for visa for Turkish citizens...

Comment: @Johnnyjanko New Zealand is even further away but doesn't charge for a visa, which my be the reason why Türkiye does not require a visa for New Zealander. All guesswork of course, since publicly the real reasons won't be mentioned.

Comment: exactly, the NZ case is the only one where reciprocity seems to play a role. That's why I didn't mention it in my previous comment ;-)